# Error when reading strings from CSV (Core Dumped)

Tags: c

I keep getting the same error, I'm new to programming so I'm not so sure if the Syntax is correct.
Every time I run it, it returns Segmentation Fault(core dumped), I'm not even sure If I can open a file with a string (address) instead of the filename in extense.
Also the files I'm reading from are CSV but in txt format.
I'm using C99

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define TAM_PERGUNTAS 128
struct question{
    char category[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    char question[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    char option1[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    char option2[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    char option3[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    char correct[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
};
struct question vec_question[BUFFER_SIZE];

void questions() {
    FILE *perguntas;
    int numaleat=0;
    int num_questions, counter = 0, index, temp_randomizer=0;
    char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char answer[32];
    char address[TAM_PERGUNTAS];
    address[0] = '\0';


    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Digite agora o numero de perguntas desejadas.(MAX 20) : "); //Insert Number of questions
    scanf("%d", &num_questions);
    printf("\n");

    for (counter = 0; counter < num_questions; counter++) {
        temp_randomizer = rand() % j; //j Represents the number o CATEGORIES at play and acts as a marker in the SELECTION string
        sprintf(address, "%s.txt", SELECTION[temp_randomizer]);
        perguntas = fopen(address, "r");
        if (perguntas == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR OPENING FILE!");
        }
            index = 0;
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), perguntas) != NULL) {
                strcpy(vec_question[index].category, strtok(line, ";"));
                strcpy(vec_question[index].question, strtok(NULL, ";"));
                strcpy(vec_question[index].option1, strtok(NULL, ";"));
                strcpy(vec_question[index].option2, strtok(NULL, ";"));
                strcpy(vec_question[index].option3, strtok(NULL, ";"));
                strcpy(vec_question[index].correct, strtok(NULL, ";"));
                vec_question[index].correct[strlen(vec_question[index].correct) - 1] = '\0';
                index++;
            }
            fclose(perguntas);
            index = 20;
            numaleat = rand() % index;
            printf("%s : %s\n%s\n%s\n%s",vec_question[numaleat].category,vec_question[numaleat].question,vec_question[numaleat].option1,vec_question[numaleat].option2,vec_question[numaleat].option3);


            for (int i = 0; i < num_users; i++) {
                printf("\n%s: ", &users[i][20]);
                scanf("%s", &answer[32]);
                if (answer == vec_question[numaleat].correct)
                    userspoints[i] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char answer[32]; ... scanf("%s", &answer[32]);` makes no sense. When using %s, you need to pass the address of the beginning of a buffer large enough to hold the input string. (Which, in the case of %s, means you need to pass an infiinitely large buffer). Try: `char answer[32]; ... scanf("%s31s", answer);`

Comment: @WilliamPursell,  regarding: `scanf("%s31s"`  this is nonsense.  Suggest: `scanf("%31s"`

Comment: regarding: `temp_randomizer = rand() % j;`  the variable: `j` is never declared nor initialized in the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `vec_question[index].correct[strlen(vec_question[index].correct) - 1] = '\0';`  Are you trying to remove a trailing newline?  if so, then the first statement in that code block should be: line[ strspan( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` and remove that last line

Answer (score 1):

In general one should assume that functions like strtok can fail.
Sometimes it fails and returns a NULL value.  A short record in your input is a likely cause.

Consider using it with a loop, and breaking out of the loop once strtok returns NULL.

I found a simple example [here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char str[80] = "This is - www.tutorialspoint.com - website";
   const char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;
   
   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   
   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   
   return(0);
}
```

Note that it does one strtok to get the first token.  That might return NULL in which case the loop doesn't run.   If it doesn't return NULL then it prints that token, and asks strtok for the next token.  It keeps doing that until strtok returns NULL.